# Is there a quick way to find the global quantile of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to find the 20th quantile of a pandas `dataframe` through and through, not per column. I know that the `.quantile` function can find the quantiles along a specific axis, but is there a fast shortcut to find the quantile of the whole `dataframe`, provided that all of its columns are integers?

Example of the desired result using a pandas `series` as a mediator:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df= pd.DataFrame(data={1: [55, 11, 13, 9, 11],
                           2: [56, 75, 31, 1, 25]})
>>> df.quantile(.2)  # this finds two quantiles, one per column
1    10.6
2    20.2
Name: 0.2, dtype: float64
# The workaround
>>> s = df[1].append(df[2])
>>> s.quantile(.2)
10.6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use numpy's [**`np.quantile`** [numpy-doc]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html) for that:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.quantile(df, 0.2)
10.6
```

Or we can use the numpy library import in the pandas module directly:

```
>>> pd.np.quantile(df, 0.2)
10.6
```

Comment: Thank you for the elegant response. As this requires importing an additional library, I found WeNYoBen's answer to be more straightforward.

Comment: @Rafi: `numpy` is implictly import by pandas, since in essence a pandas dataframe is a numpy object "with things" :)

Comment: Indeed; I'm not sure about the overhead of importing the library explicitly though. One line of code less at least :p

Comment: @Rafi: strictly speaking not, you can use `pd.np.quantile(df, 0.2)` :p If you ever imported numpy *after* you imported pandas, you have probably noticed that this takes a marginal amount of time, that is the main reason, you only import an identifier, not the library itself anymore.

Comment: Really insightful to a person at my level. Can you update your answer to include the `pd.np` version instead/as well?

Comment: `FutureWarning: The pandas.np module is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Import numpy directly instead`.

Answer (score 2):

So here is `melt`

```
df.melt().value.quantile(0.2)
Out[309]: 10.6
```